# Calculate the difference between two dates and times

Tags: c#

I'm having problem in calculating the difference between two days using form in Visual Studio c#. I was trying to use TimeSpan but I want the messagebox to display a message. How to use if statement in this matter?

```
DateTime startDate = (DateTime)datePreviDate.Value;
DateTime endDate = (DateTime)datecurrentTime.Value;
TimeSpan ts = endDate.Subtract(startDate);

//Here i want to put if statemnet like 
//if the difference of days are less than 2  AND PREVTIME + CURRENT TIME
//IS LESS THEN 24 
//then MessageBox.Show.("you CANNOT CHANGE THE DATE")
//else MessageBox.Show.("you APPOINTMENT HAS BEEN CHANGED")
MessageBox.Show(ts.Days.ToString());
```

[form image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zqp5.jpg)

Comment: i am using form where i have dateTimepicker as starting date and another one as endDate. i want if startDate == endDate Message show "something" else "another thing "

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of hard to understand what you want. But this might help you. I am assuming "PREVTIME" and "CURRENTTIME" are assigned previously. I'm also just turning your comments into logic. Not sure if this is what you meant.

```
DateTime start =  (DateTime)datePreviDate.Value;
DateTime end = (DateTime)datecurrentTime.Value;
var timespan = end - start
var totalTime = PREVTIME + CURRENTTIME;
if(timespan.TotalDays > 2 && totalTime < 24){
   MessageBox.Show("You Cannot Change The Date");
   //Continue Code Here
} else {
   MessageBox.Show("Your Appointment Has Been Changed");
   //Continue Code Here
}
```

Comment: thanks Dude i am trying to do so, but the error message comes here var totalTime = end + start; saying the operand '+' cannot be applied to operand of the type system.Datetime

Comment: well, that's because end + start doesn't make sense. What is July 1st plus august 2nd? Clearly define what you are trying to do, then I can help you solve your problem. Typically you add durations to times such as July 1st plus 24 Hours = July 2nd

Comment: i think it will be more clear if i could send the picture of the form that i have created but here i tried to upload but didn't accept. However, assuming that you have two DateTimepicker 1 and DateTimepicker2 in your form and the change button and want to say if DateTimepicker1 == DateTimepicker2 DO THIS ELSE DO ANOTHER

Comment: do dateTimePicker1 and dateTimePicker2 return datetime objects or strings? Eitherway it's easy. Just write if(DateTimePicker1 == DateTimePicker2) { //do something} else { // do something else }

Comment: it looks easy but is killing me cuz i want the difference of a time also and compare if is less than 24 hours reject otherwise accept

Comment: What is it that you don't understand? DateTime - DateTime = Timespan. A timespan is a length of time. Compare the Timespan to 24 Hours and act accordingly.